# Biblatex: "reading" style is showing the "references in source" of my bib entries

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex

As i'm about to make an annotated bibliography, I'm using the "reading" style of Biblatex to show it, and the output is pretty good but there is one problem left : the output shows the reference in source of my bib entries.

For instance, if I have in my bib file something like that :

```
@book{ReferenceInSource1,
   author="Doe, John",
   title="Original title",
}
```

The output will show "Doe: Original title" as heading of the entry in the bibliography (that's ok), but also "ReferenceInSource1".

Is there a way to hide the "ReferenceInSource1" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `entrykey=false` option:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=reading,entrykey=false]{biblatex}
```

Comment: I was toring my hair on it and didn't found that in the documentation... Thank you very much :-)